# GDB: Printing binary values omits leading zero?

Tags: gdb, nasm, yasm

I'm writing some simple assembly programs with the y assembler. However, I've noticed that although I can examine binary values in memory just fine, printing them (in the registers) omits a leading zero. This keeps catching me off guard, and so I'm wondering if there is a reason for it.

---

#### Program

```
    segment .data

f   dd  2.25        ; 32-bit floating point.

    segment .text
    global main

main:
    mov eax, [f]
    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

---

#### GDB

After setting a break point on the line corresponding to `mov eax, [f]`, I get the following binary value using the examine command:

```
(gdb) x/1tw &f
0x601030:   01000000000100000000000000000000
```

I have manually verified this. However, the print command yields something different once it is loaded into the `eax` register:

```
(gdb) p/t $eax
$2 = 1000000000100000000000000000000
```

The former is 32 bits, while the latter is 31. The leading zero is omitted. Am I doing something wrong in displaying these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong in displaying these values?

No. GDB is inconsistent in its handling of leading zero between the `x` and the `p` commands, that's all.

If you want `print` to print leading zeros, use `p/tz $eax` ([documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html)).

Comment: Thanks! The tip is most helpful!

Comment: From what I see, `p/tz` is the same thing as `p/z`, which prints in hexadecimal, not binary (though it does keep leading zeroes). I cannot find a way to make GDB print in binary and include the leading zeroes. I'm on GDB 8.2.1, for reference.